# GameCenter issue - leaderboards not showing up in live game

Tags: ios, iphone, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I made a game, and first enabled leaderboards for a single game. During development, I decided to also have a premium version of the game, so I moved the leaderboards to a group.

During development, with a sandbox account, the leadeboards all showed up.

I now downloaded the free version from the app store to test, and the leaderboards are not showing up (using a real account). I did submit all the leaderboards with the game - if I check that version on iTunes Connect, all leaderboards are shown there.

EDIT : Also checked the premium versions, no leaderboards for that one either...

Any guesses as to what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a problem with iTunes Connect, which Apple confirmed to me.

Comment: They fixed it for me. I recommend either posting in the game center developer forums, or using one of your two technical support tickets.